# How do I make an existing project on my machine into a GitHub project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, github, github-for-windows

I can't believe this is taking me so long to figure out. I go to **New Repository** and the 3 options are **Add**, **Create**, **Clone**. From what I can tell, none of those do what I want. I want to take my local project at **C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyProject** and put those source files under control at GitHub. In other words, as I work on that project, I want the to be able to push/pull/sync/whatever my chances. Isn't this what GitHub is for? From what I can tell, all I can do is create a new folder for a GitHub project and then copy the files over to there. Is that right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The way I did that is to first create a github repo on github.com, then clone it on my laptop, then move my existing project into it, and finally update my github.com repo with my existing project using the GitHub tool that got installed on my laptop (along with Git Shell, Git Bash and Git Gui) and has launcher icon in my desktop. To install the GitHub tool and the other git tools mentioned, I downloaded their installer from https://windows.github.com/ and ran the downloaded executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is initialize a git repo in your root file of your project. Use `git init` in your projects root directory. Then add all files with `git add .`  and then commit them with `git commit` or `git commit -m "your commit message"`. Then create a github repo on github. The repo is just the container for your project. Once you have a new github repo you can add the remote link that it gives you in the instructions.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourgithubusername/yourgithubprojectname.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: When you say "Use `git init` in your projects root directory", what does that mean? Do I open the Windows command shell and navigate there and issue the command? Also, is there a way to do all this through the GUI?

Comment: Yes open git shell navigate to the root directory and issue the command. If you downloaded the GitHub for windows package then you should be using the Git Shell that came with that program to issue your commands. You can actually drag and drop your projects root directory onto the GitHub for windows gui to perform the same task. It is highly recommended that you learn the git commands because the gui cannot handle all situations. [Some helpful guides](https://guides.github.com/)